# How to allow all font-family values on sanitize-html?

Tags: node.js, html-sanitizing

Hi,

Im using sanitize-html and I want to allow any value for font-family so Im doing this:

```
var cleanmsg = sanitizeHtml(rawmsg, {
       allowedTags: [ 'span' ]
       allowedAttributes: {
        'span': [ 'style' ]
       },
       allowedStyles: {
        'span': {
         'font-family': true
        }
       }
      });
```

but it wont parse, I tried also this:

```
'font-family': ['.*']
```

but it doesnt work either. Why is that?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

you can use regex format

```
'font-family': [/.*/]
```